# Как сделать возможным пропускать отправку формы без прикрепленного файла?

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать возможным пропускать форму без файла, если пользователь не прикрепил файл. Заранее спасибо!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<?php
define("UPLOAD_DIR", "/home/m/meowwiif/meowwiif.beget.tech/public_html/files/"); // здесь должен быть Ваш путь

if (!empty($_FILES["myFile"]) && (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'])) {
    $myFile = $_FILES["myFile"];

    if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo "<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>";
        exit;
    }


//    $fileType = exif_imagetype($_FILES["myFile"]["tmp_name"]);


    $tmp_fail_name = explode('.',$_FILES["myFile"]['name']);

    $last_element = array_pop($tmp_fail_name);

    $symbols = '01234pqrst56789abcdefghijklmnouvwxyz';
    $file_n = substr(str_shuffle($symbols), 0, 16);




    $allowed = array("doc","docx","docm");
    if (!in_array($last_element, $allowed)) {
        echo "<a href='http://akciapdd.ru/'><div class='errorfile'></div></a>";
        exit;
    }

    $name = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);

    $i = 0;
    $parts = pathinfo($name);
    while (file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $name)) {
        $i++;
        $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
    }

    $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"],
        UPLOAD_DIR . $file_n.'.'.$last_element);
    if (!$success) { 
        echo "<a href='http://akciapdd.ru/'><div class='errorfile'></div></a>";
        exit;
    }

//$file_n.'.'.$last_element

    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0644);

    echo "<a href='http://akciapdd.ru/'><div class='successfile'></div></a>";

}

    include 'bd.php';

    $region = $_POST['region'];
    $uchname = $_POST['uchname'];
    $fio = $_POST['fio']; 
    $wname = $_POST['wname']; 
    $adress = $_POST['adress']; 
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $mp = $_POST['mp'];
    $fiorab = $_POST['fiorab']; 
    $filename = $file_n.'.'.$last_element;

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `register_user` (`region`, `uchname`, `fio`, `wname`, `adress`, `email`, `comment`,`file_name`, `mp`, `fiorab`) VALUES ('$region', '$uchname', '$fio', '$wname', '$adress' ,'$email', '$comment', '$filename', '$mp', '$fiorab')");
    if (!$result) {
        die('Неверный запрос: ' . mysql_error());
    }

?>
```

Comment: Если файла нет, как вы попадаете в ветку `if (!empty($_FILES[...]))`?

Comment: Посмотрите сами: http://akciapdd.ru/

Оставьте поле файл пустым, увидите, он выдаст ошибку о том, что тип файла не поддерживается.

Comment: @vp_arth изменил код на нынешний, он выглядит так

Comment: Так форма сработает и без  файлов что находится в bd.php?

Comment: @RuslanSemenov В bd.php только база данных

Comment: @RuslanSemenov, вы можете проверить формы сами по кнопке регистрация, ссылку приложил выше, форма, увы, не срабатывает.

Comment: `if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name']))`

Comment: @vp_arth , а можно подробнее, что нуждается в этом условии?

Comment: Просто добавьте его к `!empty($_FILES["myFile"])` через `&&`

Comment: Ну и мне он пишет "Произошла ошибка", а не про тип файлов)

Comment: В этом случае уже это:     if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo "<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>";
        exit;
    }

Comment: @vp_arth обновил код